# how to open same activity with different data when click on card view

Tags: java, android, json

I have created one horizontal recycle view with card view. I have created single card and shown it multiple times in the recycle view. The data has been shown from the web services. Now what here is the UI of app

[image]

Now what i have to do is when i click on any card then one activity should open. I have created one activity, that activity should get open when i click on any card. And base on the card data, the data should be change in the activity.

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

private List<Data> dataList;
private Context mContext;

public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(Context context, List<Data> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

    final String sectionName = dataList.get(i).getTitle();

    List singleSectionItems = dataList.get(i).getSection();

    itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(sectionName);

    SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems);

    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);


     itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


   /*  itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events once again.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
            // Handle RecyclerView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });*/

    itemRowHolder.btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "click event on more, "+sectionName , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
    });







   /* Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.bg)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != dataList ? dataList.size() : 0);
}

public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView itemTitle;

    protected RecyclerView recycler_view_list;

    protected Button btnMore;



    public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        this.itemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        this.recycler_view_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
        this.btnMore= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMore);


    }

}
```

}

another class

```
public class SectionListDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionListDataAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {

private List<Section> itemsList;
private Context mContext;



public SectionListDataAdapter(Context context, List<Section> itemsList) {
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_single_card, null);
    SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

    Section singleItem = itemsList.get(i);

    holder.tvTitle.setText(singleItem.getName());



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
}

public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView tvTitle;

    protected ImageView itemImage;


    public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        this.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle1);
        this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);


        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BooksDescription.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    `}

}}`
```

Comment: pass the data with intent to another activity

Comment: when call to same activity use Bundle to change data..

Answer (score 1):

1- you can pass your desired data(for example :id or whole object) to your activity and then handle that in your activity:
`Intent.putExtra("YOUR_KEY","YOUR_SERIALIZED_OBJECT_OR_STRING");`

2-please do not setOnClickListener in your onBindViewHolder(in your first adapter) , it is better to put it in your viewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

U need to implement item click listener . to implement recyclerview item clicklistner follow this [link](http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/)

And then Pass your data through intent , this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

will help you in passing data to activity and then getting it on the other side

Comment: you are using clicklistner of cardview in viewholder which will work but its good to implement itemclikclistner if you hae a single action in whole item

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in your adapter OnClick Listener

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BooksDescription.class);
intent.putExtra("YOUR KEY", yourData);
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```